# how to measure number of | in a file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file ($file) that contents this:

FirstName,LastName,Age,Birthday,Address,mobile

so for my script, I say

`$comma = get-content $file | select-string -pattern "," -allMatches`

`$comma.matches.count`

and this return with a result of 5, it contain 5 commas

but when I some how do this:

`$pipe = get-content $file | select-string -pattern "|" -allMatches`

`$pipe.matches.count`

and this return with a result of 47

it didn't contain any pipe and it looks like it return with no. of characters

so how to measure no. of | in a file in powershell?

the purpose of the script is to determine the delimiter in a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|` is special character in regular expressions and needs to be escaped. Try this way:

```
("S|d|f|h" | Select-String '\|' -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

Mixing with your example, it would be:

```
$total = (cat $file | Select-String "\|" -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

Answer (score 2):

In `regex`, the pattern `|` literally means "nothing or nothing" - your string is 46 characters, so there are at least 47 index positions at which "nothing" exists.

You'll need to escape the `|` with `\`:

```
Select-String '\|' -AllMatches
```

An alternative solution would be to split every string by `|` and see how many pieces you end up with:

```
$pipeCount = @("FirstName,LastName,Age,Birthday,Address,mobile" -split '\|').Count - 1
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That will only give you a boolean answer (ie. does each string contain at least one instance of `|` or not) - it won't give you the exact count